# How to unit test static callback routine called from ISR

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmock, ceedling

I am using ceedling to unit test a C application and trying to achieve high coverage ~100%.

I have a static callback function in one of my application module, which is registered to SDK function with function pointer and is called at certain event from the SDK.

In appModule.c,

```
typedef void( *type_appCallback ) ( void );

static void appCallback( void );
```

I want to unit test this function and since this functions is static will not be seen in the ceedling test_appModule.c.
I have a work around to this define `TEST_STATIC` instead of `static`,

```
#ifdef TEST 
TEST_STATIC
#else
TEST_STATIC static
#endif
```

But I am not big fan of this work around, any suggestions to above problem?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use a wrapper module that includes the **C** file.

wrap_app_Module.c

```
/* include code of static function (.c is intentional, not .h) */
#include "appModule.c"

void wrap_appCallback(void)
{
    appCallback();
}
```

Instead of the `static` function you can call the wrapper function in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to what @Bodo suggested above using the CMock callback plugin. Note the cmockNumCalls is a mandatory parameter for the stub function

Production code -> setCallback( funcAddress );

Unit Test code  -> setCallback_Stub( storeFuncAddress );

Where storeFuncAddress looks like

```
void storeFuncAddress(
      type_appCallback       appCallbackFn,
      int                    cmockNumCalls)
{
    l_storedCallbackFn = appCallbackFn;
}
```

When the _Stub version gets called it passes the same parameters to the registered callback function so storeFuncAddress receives the same function address (which is a pointer to a static) and stores it in a variable of type type_appCallback which I'm calling l_storedCallbackFn.

The second part is where the event gets triggered.

Production code -> triggerCallback();

Unit Test code  -> triggerCallback_Stub( runStoredCallbackFunction );

Where my runStoredCallbackFunction function looks like

```
void runStoredCallbackFunction(
    int                       cmockNumCalls)
{
    (*l_storedCallbackFn)(NULL);
}
```

Hopefully this helps you or the next person who runs across this same question.